# Can't change UIImageView image in function (SWIFT)

Tags: swift, xcode, image, function, uiimageview

I have called this function after it is declared and everything works but the UIImageViews don't change their image. I would be very grateful for your help.

[image: My Code]

Comment: You need to include your code in your question, as a code block, not as an image.

Comment: Are you sure you run this code in a main queue?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in there and see what is being executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is the sleep(3), this line block the main thread.
Instead of that use:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) {
    // your code here
}
```

Apple Reference

> Note:
>   For the most part, use UIKit classes only from your app’s main thread. This is particularly true for classes derived from UIResponder or that involve manipulating your app’s user interface in any way.

Regards

Comment: The problem was the use of sleep(3). I used `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) {
    // your code here
}` and it worked perfectly! Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you are updating your image either in main thread or background.  Don't use sleep, Instead try updating your image in main thread asynchronously with delay.

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(3))
{ self.GreenImage.image = UIImage }
```